# Opening a pdf in webview needs more than 5 clicks or no load

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to open pdf with a webview but some pdf says "No Preview Avaliable", or you have to give it many clicks to open it or directly some crash the app.

Im using the web `https://www.pdfpdf.com/samples.html` and the first 5 pdfs work fine although sometimes I have to click them 5 times to open them. With those of the last sections, the app crashes when I click on one of them.

The following code can work if I open the pdf in WebView directly .

This is my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="webviewproblema.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView
            x:Name="Browser"
            HeightRequest="1000"
            Navigating="Browser_Navigating"
            Source="{Binding HTMLContent}"
            WidthRequest="1000" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public string HTMLContent { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
      
        InitializeComponent();
       
        Browser.Source = "https://www.pdfpdf.com/samples.html";
    }

    private void Browser_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {

        // With this,the app crash
        //string url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(e.Url);

        Browser.IsVisible = true;
            string url = e.Url;


        if ( e.Url.EndsWith(".pdf") || e.Url.EndsWith(".PDF") && !e.Url.Contains("drive.google.com"))
        {
            Browser.Source = "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + url;
        }
      

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use custom renderer to open external link in a website .

#### In forms

Create a custom webview

```
public class MyWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(MyWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

#### in Android project

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net.Http;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;
using App32;
using App32.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App32.Droid
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        Context _context;
        public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Android.Webkit.WebView web_view = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
                web_view.LoadUrl(((MyWebView)Element).Uri);
            
                web_view.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

           

                SetNativeControl(web_view);
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
               
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override void OnReceivedSslError(Android.Webkit.WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
        {
            handler.Proceed();
        }

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {

            var url = request.Url.ToString();

            if (request.Url.ToString().EndsWith(".pdf") || request.Url.ToString().EndsWith(".PDF") && !request.Url.ToString().Contains("drive.google.com"))
            {

                view.LoadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + request.Url.ToString());
                view.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

#### in iOS project

```
using System;
using App32;
using App32.iOS;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;
using UIKit;
using WebKit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(MyWebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App32.iOS
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyWebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView _wkWebView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                _wkWebView.NavigationDelegate = new MyDelegete();
                SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
            }

            if(e.NewElement!=null)
            {
                var webview = Element as MyWebView;

                var url = webview.Uri;

                if (url.EndsWith(".pdf") || url.EndsWith(".PDF") && !url.Contains("drive.google.com"))
                {

                    Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + webview.Uri)));
                }

                else
                {
                    Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(webview.Uri)));
                }


                
            }

        }
        

    }

    public class MyDelegete :WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, WKWebpagePreferences preferences, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences> decisionHandler)
        {
            //  base.DecidePolicy(webView, navigationAction, preferences, decisionHandler);

            var url = navigationAction.Request.Url.ToString();

            if (url.EndsWith(".pdf") || url.EndsWith(".PDF") && !url.Contains("drive.google.com"))
            {

                webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + url)));
            }

          

            decisionHandler.Invoke(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow, preferences);

        }
    }

}
```

#### in xaml

Now you can use it in xaml like

```
<StackLayout>

        <local:MyWebView  x:Name="Browser"  Uri="https://xxx" HeightRequest="1000" WidthRequest="1000" />

    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to use embedded html instead of a url? Would it be very difficult to implement?

Comment: Just need to set the load url . For example , in Android , put the html file in Assets-> Content folder(create a new folder ) . And invoke `Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/Content/{((MyWebView)Element).Uri}");`